# Relation between the convergence of measures and the evolution of their supports

Tags: measure-theory

Let a sequence of Borel probability measures $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ in the weak*-topology. Are there any related results on the evolution of the support of $\mu_n$?

For example, in which case, the following holds: for all $\epsilon>0$, there is $N\geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq N$, the support of $\mu_n$ is contained in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the support of $\mu$?

Comment: No, consider $(1-\varepsilon)\delta_{x_1} + \varepsilon \delta_{x_2}$ for two distinct points $x_1, x_2$.

Comment: You might be looking for the Portmanteau Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures

Comment: What is true, though, is that for every $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$, there exists $N \geq 0$ and  such that for all $n \geq N$, $\mu_n (E_\varepsilon) > 1 - \delta$, where $E_\varepsilon$ is the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of the support of $\mu$.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that if you take an infinitesimal amount of the mass of a measure $\mu$ and spread it somewhere else, it changes the measure only infinitesimally with respect to the weak-* topology, but it can make its support tremendously larger.

Answer (score 4):

There's a "semicontinuity" property: the support of $\mu$ is not larger than the "limit" of the supports of the $\mu_n$.  Specifically, letting $S(\mu_n), S(\mu)$ denote the supports, we have
$$S(\mu) \subseteq \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \overline{\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty S(\mu_n)}.$$
This follows directly from the portmanteau theorem.

It's not really possible to have any result in the other direction.  For instance, let $\mu_n$ be a normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ with mean 0 and variance $1/n$.  Then the support of each $\mu_n$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$, but they converge weak-* to a point mass at 0.